# Get a column from the latest row by another column

Tags: sql-server, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

Take a look at this [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/03951/4/0). I have a table that contains history of records for another table(irrelevant, foreign key included). Each history item will contain a status and time fields. I want to write a select statement that would give me a list of unique(by foreign key) histories with the latest status.

From other searches I think what I need is

```
SELECT MAX(created) as created, originalMsgId 
from ReplayHistory 
group by originalMsgId
```

```
created             Id
------------------------
2018-06-22 19:18:43 11
2018-06-22 09:28:43 12
```

but it doesn't return the column I need; status.

The query I am using is

```
SELECT MAX(created) as created, originalMsgId, status 
from ReplayHistory 
group by originalMsgId, status
```

which returns me

```
created              Id  status
----------------------------------
2018-06-22 19:18:43  11  Finished
2018-06-22 19:17:43  11  InProgress
2018-06-22 09:28:43  12  InProgress
2018-06-22 19:16:43  11  NotStarted
2018-06-22 09:27:43  12  NotStarted
```

I know that this is happening because of group by status, but if I need it in select then I have to keep it in group by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use for a window function, `row_number()`

```
select 
   x.created, 
   x.OriginalMsgId, 
   x.Status
from (SELECT 
         RN = row_number() over (partition by r.originalMsgId order by Created desc), 
         r.originalMsgId, 
         r.status, 
         created 
      from ReplayHistory r) x
where x.RN = 1
```

Another way is using `MAX` with a derived table.

```
SELECT 
   r.originalMsgId, 
   r.status, 
   r.created 
from ReplayHistory r
inner join
    (select originalMsgId, max(created) dt from ReplayHistory group by originalMsgId) x on
    x.dt = r.created 
    and x.originalMsgId = r.originalMsgId
```

[Notes on performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233125/is-there-a-performance-difference-in-using-a-group-by-with-max-as-the-aggregat)

Comment: the second query might not work if you have multiple rows with the same value in 'created' column

Comment: Correct @TahaRehmanSiddiqui but i wouldn't have expected the exact time down to the second for a given ID. This means that an ID would have to have duplicate data or change status twice in a second (presumably). If that's a possibility, then you are correct

Comment: Youre right, might not happen in real world. I have duplicated data in my table that I put for testing.

Comment: By the way? Any idea if the query would run in mysql and oracle as well?

Comment: I'm not versed on those platforms, but the second one should work in MySQL (not sure about Oracle but I'd think so). I don't think MySQL has row_number, but [**here's a post on that **](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql). Oracle does however , [**listed in the docs at least**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm)

Comment: The first one does not :( I have a mybatis running with all 3 databases connected to it, and for some complex queries I define separate queries for each environment.